# Does applying GPU Core Image filter to AVPlayerLayer always incur high CPU usage?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, core-image

OSX Desktop app written in Obj-C.

I have a video player application and I would like to apply a CIFilter (specifically CIColorMap) to the playing video. I've created a custom layer view which contains a "stack" of layers so that I can visually layer more than one video. The video is added as an AVPlayerLayer and then I am applying the CIfilter to the parent layer of the whole stack, which filters everything.

This works, however without the filter applied, my CPU usage is 1-5%, and with the filter applied it jumps to 25%.

```
CIFilter *colorMapFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMap"];
[colorMapFilter setValue:colormapImage forKey:@"inputGradientImage"];
[baseLayer setFilters:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[colorMapFilter]]];
```

I have verified that the filter is being applied on the GPU using CI_PRINT_TREE:

[image]

I have also profiled the code and can see the issue is in the guts of core image:

[image]

But now I hit the limit of my knowledge. 25-30% increase in CPU usage seems rather high to me, especially as I think the filter is being run on the GPU. Am I doing this wrong or is this normal behavior?

Comment: Not particularly scientific, but I think the answer is "yes" based on similar CPU usage by Apple's own Photobooth application with and without the "Infrared" filter, which I'm assuming is a colormap filter. I'm still not sure where this is coming from. I'll keep investigating.